# Slight keyboard lag on Macbook Air 2020, Ventura 13.2

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, ventura

A few weeks ago my laptop started to get a tiny but noticeable keyboard lag, maybe 1/10th of a second between hitting a key and it showing up on the screen. I think it used to be intermittent and would resolve when I restarted, but now it's permanent.

Details: Macbook Air M1, 2020, 8GB memory, MacOS 13.2 Ventura.

Things I tried that didn't work:

- Restart: I think it used to help, but doesn't help now.
- Start up in safe mode.
- Reinstall MacOS Ventura (2023-01-26), took about 45 minutes.
- Kill any background processes consuming CPU.
- Check temperature: laptop is not hot and CPU usage very low.
- Disable bluetooth: I get the same lag on the laptop keyboard with bluetooth disconnected. I also tried disconnecting and reconnecting bluetooth accessories while in Safe model.
- Disable "slow keys" in Settings.
- Reset SMC: Apple says you don't need to for Apple Silicon macs, a restart is sufficient.
- Reset NVRAM: `sudo nvram -c`.
- Kill bluetooth daemon: `sudo pkill bluetoothd`
- Quit apps running in background. (Alfred, Rectangle, Dropbox, System Monitor, Itsycal).
- Connect power cord.
- Try lag in different apps. I get the lag in vscode, sublime, and Apple Notes
- Run apple Diagnostics. Couldnt' find any errors.
- Run CleanMyMac. CleanMyMac and ran the following: "free up ram", "run maintenance scripts", "flush DNS cache"
- Delete files from /Cache/.
- Disable all "allow in the background" apps.
- Call Apple support. They only recommended disabling the "slow keys" setting, didn't have any other ideas.
- Run EtreCheck (recommended removing a couple of apps, I removed them)

I thought about taking it in to an Apple store but I'm not confident they'd be able to do anything for me if I can't find anything online about this problem.

Comment: What were the results when you booted into Safe Mode?  This mode doesn't fix anything, it just boots with no 3rd party apps/kexts loaded.  It's a *diagnostic* mode.

Comment: The keyboard lag is still there when I boot into safe mode -- i.e. that seems to rule out 3rd-party apps as causing the problem.

Comment: The built-in keyboard is a USB device.  Try plugging in a generic USB keyboard to see if you still have difficulty.

Comment: Hm that's a good idea, unfortunately I realize I don't have any plug-in USB keyboards anymore. Do you think it's plausible enough that it's worth getting a plug-in keyboard to try it out.

Comment: It’s always good to keep a spare keyboard around. Any cheap one will work fine

Comment: I am having the same issue with the Apple MagicKeyboard as once I plug it to the laptop it works fine, but it has a minor lag when using bluetooth!

Comment: Same here as @AmirHajiha. I'm using a MagicKeyboard. Plugged in, it's quite reasonable, but via bluetooth there's a very noticeable lag. It seems variable; I'd estimate from 100ms up to 500ms!

Comment: Update: I removed and then repaired my keyboard and it eliminated the delay. Seems to still be working after a restart.